# Управляющие последовательности. Как перевести курсор в конец строки?

Tags: c, esc

Принимающая сторона - терминал Putty, если это важно. 
При отправке неизвестно, какую ширину имеет экран терминала. Как выровнять текст по правому краю? Имхо есть соответствующая последовательность, но ничего пока не нашел на эту тему.

Конкретно нужно так:

```
TEXT:                                TEXT2
TEXT3:                                TXT3    
 ...
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Появилась еще мысль. Можно ли установить размер терминала с помощью последовательностей? Забыл сразу уточнить - передающая и принимающая сторона - разные машины, соединенные по COM. Причем передающая ограничена в возможностях (контроллер,библиотек потипа libtermios и др. под него нет), поэтому и интересуют именно последовательности.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <term.h>

int main() {
    int rows, cols;
    char txt1[] = "TEXT_1 :", txt2[] = "TEXT_2";

    //самая главная часть - получение геометрии терминала
    setupterm (NULL, fileno (stdout), (int*) 0);    
    rows = tigetnum ("lines");
    cols = tigetnum ("cols");

    int y = printf ("%s", txt1);

  //\e[{N}C - перемещение курсора на N позиций вправо
    printf ("\e[%luC%s\n", cols - sizeof(txt2) - y, txt2);

    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции нужно линковать с библиотекой libtinfo:

```
gcc prog.c -o prog -ltinfo
```

Answer (score 2):

[[@decodder](/users/2376/decodder)](/users/2376/decodder), если еще интересно, вот программка читающая ширину экрана (ANSI-terminal).

Проверял в gnome-terminal ubuntu 10.04

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void
setup_scr (struct termios *oldt) 
{
  struct termios newt;
  int tty = fileno(stdin);

  tcgetattr ( tty, oldt );
  newt = *oldt;
  newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
  tcsetattr ( tty, TCSANOW, &newt );
}

void
restore_scr (struct termios *oldt)
{
  tcsetattr ( fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, oldt );
}

main ()
{
  struct termios targs;
  setup_scr(&targs);
  int row, col;

  // Save current cursor <ESC>7 and move cursor 1000 positions right
  fputs("\e7\e[1000C",stdout);

  // Query Cursor Position  <ESC>[6n
  printf("\e[6n"); fflush(stdout);
  // Get Report Cursor Position <ESC>[{ROW};{COLUMN}R
  getchar(); getchar();
  scanf("%d;%d",&row,&col);
  getchar();

  // Restore Cursor & Attrs <ESC>8
  fputs("\e8",stdout);
  restore_scr(&targs);

  printf ("Row = %d Col = %d\n",row,col);
}

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc termwidth.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Row = 33 Col = 109
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Row = 24 Col = 80
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Тут я просто окошко мышкой порастягивал, а потом вернул к 24x80

---

Поторопился, забыл **главное**. Когда мы пытаемся сдвинуть курсор за границу экрана, он **остается на границе**. Собственно на этом (нигде не читал, наикнулся в процессе...) факте и основана программка.

Comment: Принимающая и передающая сторона, соединенные через COM порт. Сработает ли в этом случае?

Comment: Поподробнее пожалуйста. Что с чем и по каким протоколам (физику не надо) соединено. 

Если правильно понял, то на стороне программы, желающей узнать ширину экрана libtermios нет. Она соединена с putty по tty (pty) или по сокету ? 

Собственно tcsetattr() из libtermios (если правильно понимаю) нужна только для перевода терминала в режим вывода без эхо и ввода без ожидания <Enter>. Если файловый дескриптор (в конце концов связанный с putty) связан с сокетом, то проблем нет. Иначе (для tty интерфейса) Вам надо как-то перевести этот интерфейс хотя бы в ... (места мало, продолж. след.)

Comment: *продолжение*


состояние ввода без ожидания. Аналогично надо настроить putty.

Естественно, вместо stdout и stdin (printf(), getchar() в моей программке) Вам надо делать fprintf(), fgtec() с нужным файловым дескриптором (и не забывайте fflush()) или делайте просто на read()/write().

А вообще такие штуки надо просто пробовать. У меня аналогичной конфигурации, конечно, нет.

Comment: По поводу протокола - связь по RS232. Соединение через COM.
Дело в том, что передающее устройство не компьютер, а контроллер. Пользователи могут быть всякие, поэтому и не хотелось бы прибегать к настройкам на принимающей стороне - типа открыл терминал и все работает как надо. Если есть необходимость настраивать принимающий терминал, то можно и ширину его настроить на определенную. А зная ширину терм-ла на передающей стороне, можно выводить куда нужно. Запутанно наверное написал...

Comment: Может быть я вообще не на том зациклился?

Comment: @decodder, Теперь я не понимаю.

Вы пишите программу на Си, встроенную в некую железяку, подключаемую к хосту (ОС какая ???) по RS232 ?

По этому порту (RS232) с точки зрения хоста терминал ? Как user на хосте Putty к этому порту подсоединяет ?

    putty  is  a  graphical  SSH,  Telnet and Rlogin client for X. It is a
       direct port of the Windows SSH client of the same name.

Распишите архитектуру подробнее.

Comment: @avp я не телепат, но подозреваю, что в реальности д.б. не putty, а терминалка. А канитель с ssh -- просто отработка решения на персоналке.

Comment: @alexsz - да, pytty используется исключительно как терминал. SSH тут не причем. @avp - именно в железяку)), ОС хоста в данный момент WIndows, хотя наверное разницы нет.
 ` Как user на хосте Putty к этому порту подсоединяет ?` - не совсем понял, точнее не знаю как ответить. В настройках Session - Serial.

Comment: @decodder, что-то я окончательно запутался. Вам решение надо "для сейчас с putty" (правда не пронимаю, как Вы с ней соединяетесь) или "для потом" ? Впрочем это наверное не так важно. 

Вы сейчас просто попробуйте эскейп последовательности из этой программы. Если не собирается, то setup/restore выбрасывайте. Если сразу не выведет Row = ... - жмите ENTER.

--

А вообще, чем подробней распишите **что конкретно сейчас делаете** (в смысле что где запускаете и в чем какие буковки видите), тем скорее Вам смогут правильно ответить.

Answer (score 1):

В Unix консоли есть переменная `$COLUMNS`. Ее можно использовать для форматирования вывода. В bash это будет примерно так

```
#!/bin/bash

LEFT="Left"
RIGHT="righT"
echo -ne ${LEFT}
let COUNTER=${#LEFT}+${#RIGHT}
while [ ${COUNTER} -lt ${COLUMNS} ] 
do 
   let COUNTER=${COUNTER}+1
   echo -ne " "
done
echo ${RIGHT}
```

Comment: Собственно esc-последовательности можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)

Comment: Интересно, но наверное больше подходит для скриптов..